# Trying to obtain the voltage amplitude at the input of the RFFE

Tags: power, rf

[image]

So after converting dBm to W (P) , i would say all i had to do is

$$\ P = (\frac{V^2}{R})$$ and solve for V , with R = 50.

But perhaps i should i consider taking the maximum power transform equation :

$$\ P = (\frac{V^2}{4R})$$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first formula gives the rms voltage of the signal at the input.

Notice that the question specifically says the rms voltage is not what's being asked for. After calculating the rms voltage you must further determine the corresponding signal amplitude.

The amplitude is the \$A\$ in
$$v(t) = A \sin(\omega t + \phi)$$

Comment: Wouldnt the rms voltage be U^2 / 2R ? Because in the first formula i didnt divide by sqrt(2)

Comment: @G0tBlackOps, for time-varying signals, the power is calculated as \$P=V_{rms}^2/R\$. The fact that the rms voltage plugs into this formula to give the power is essentially the whole reason the rms voltage is useful.

Comment: so i must just Multiply Vrms with sqrt(2) ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.